# Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Он улыбнулся: "совпадение" - это слово не переставало его веселить.

Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания?

Comment: В чем, собственно, вопрос? 

Comment: @Мария Шакарова, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Возможно так: Он улыбнулся. "Совпадение" - это слово не переставало его веселить.

Comment: Да, с точкой спокойнее. Двоеточие наводит на такую мысль: он не сразу улыбнулся - сначала убедился, что слово не перестаёт веселить?

Answer (score 0):

Он улыбнулся: "совпадение". Это слово не переставало его веселить.